# How to take one field with binary data, parse it as Json and propagate further with columns from Json in pyspark/kafka?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading my `Kafka` topic with the following code:

```
builder = SparkSession.builder\
   .appName("PythonTest08")

spark = builder.getOrCreate()

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
  .option("subscribe", dataFlowTopic) \
  .load()
```

The example output can be following

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+----+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|               value|   topic|partition| offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------------------+-------------+
|null|[7B 22 70 6C 75 6...|dataflow|        0|3512872|2021-04-06 00:46:...|            0|
+----+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------------------+-------------+
```

where `value` is binary encoded Json.

How to extract it, infer schema from it and obtain new stream with it's columns?

Can I just map it with Python function?

---

I wrote separate script to infer schema from JSON example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Infer Schema") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .read \
    .option("multiline", True) \
    .json("file_examples/dataflow/row01.json")

df.printSchema()

df.show()

with open("dataflow_schema.json", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(df.schema.json())
```

Then I tried to use it in structured streaming

```
builder = SparkSession.builder\
   .appName("PythonTest10")


spark = builder.getOrCreate()


# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
  .option("subscribe", dataFlowTopic) \
  .load()

with open("dataflow_schema.json") as fp:
    schema = StructType.fromJson(json.load(fp))

df = df \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))

df.printSchema()

# Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

It prints the following schema

```
root
 |-- parsed_value: struct (nullable = true)
...
 |    |-- pluginVersion: string (nullable = true)
...
```

Unfortunately, on posting this JSON

```
>{"pluginVersion":"0.1"
...
}
```

(i.e. one JSON object) to Kafka stream I get the following output

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+
|        parsed_value|
+--------------------+
|{null, null, null...|
+--------------------+
```

Does this mean that schema is incorrect or some other made wrong?

Comment: Can you please show your schema file? And what the full messages are?

Comment: Schema was ok. I found this is because of truncation to 4096. But I don't know, why truncation is happening...